# Split 2D trajectories into points with equal intervals

Tags: python, arrays, cluster-analysis, similarity, polyline

I want to cluster trajectories using euclidean distance. However, the points composing the trajectories are not in the same number. So I need to break each one with an equal number of points and compute them accordingly.

For example, I have one trajectory composed by an array of 2D points (they are not in the same intervals).

```
[(0.0, 13.935130773499658),  
(0.9206715658615288, 87.63458690840814), 
(1.2245818835622884, 111.96041116227424),  
(1.6280390619875555,144.22535883207814),  
(2.4687774761711263, 211.49397181142362),  
(2.8179447735365812, 239.4273556006593),  
(3.2963389341232032, 239.4273556006593),  
(4.527849090835078, 239.4273556006593), 
(6.05237501176546, 969.4543366873916), 
(6.05237501176546, 969.4543366873916),  
(7.427758223451998, 969.4543366873916),  
(9.628371362150414, 969.4543366873916),  
(15.369101289189876, 3961.68816425364),  
(17.234838515477744, 4861.421805491894),  
(17.234838515477744, 4861.421805491894),  
(18.400924281907635,4861.421805491894),  
(18.628546140914224, 4879.631554212427),  
(18.778532556213293, 4891.665691215202), 
(18.912718114201468,4902.404931114517),  
(19.051842229505283, 4913.539707867735),  
(19.449597896390035, 4944.813545621106),  
(19.841058908365085,4976.143225350869), 
 (20.13926859147929, 5000.0)]
```

It gives the scatter and line chart as below:

[image]

[image]

What I want to do is to identify points splitting the whole trajectory into the same length of pieces. For example, 30 points. How should I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

- generating the point-slope form for each consecutive pair of points
- picking values along some axis of it

```py
for index in range(len(my_points) - 1):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = my_points[index:index + 1]
    # _y = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (_x - x1) + y1
```

you could generate an anonymous function for this position, but it's probably more useful to just keep the original list and generate on the fly

---

If you want to map the set of points across a range smaller than the set of points, then you need to pick what to do with intermediate points, such as averaging them or always picking one side